# g++ compiler optimization: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’

Tags: c++11, optimization, g++

Following code not compiling:

**A.h**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

namespace net {

        using Ip = in_addr_t;
        using Port = in_port_t;
        using SockFd = int;

        class Params final {
        public:
                Ip getIp() const { return ip_; }
                Port getPort() const { return port_; }

        private:
                Ip ip_ {INADDR_ANY};
                Port port_ {htons(5)};
        };

}
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "A.h"

int main(){
        net::Params a {};

        std::cout << "Ip=" << a.getIp() << ", Port=" << a.getPort() << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
g++-6 -O2 -std=c++11 A.cpp
```

**Error:**

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/endian.h:60,
                 from /usr/include/ctype.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/cctype:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/localefwd.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from A.cpp:1:
A.h:21:15: error: statement-expressions are not allowed outside functions nor in template-argument lists
   Port port_ {htons(5)};
               ^
In file included from A.cpp:3:0:
A.h:21:23: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘net::Port {aka short unsigned int}’ in initialization
   Port port_ {htons(5)};
                       ^
```

But when I change `port_` member variable initialization to: `Port port_ {5};`, g++ with -O2 compiles fine.

Above code compiles fine without optimization flag, whether `port_` initialized as: `Port port_ {htons(5)};` or as `Port port_ {5};`

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a ompiler and/or libstd bug. The compiler tries to optimize away the function call to htons with some macros and compiler magic. That results in some problem I do not understand. But you can define an inline function myhtons that calls htons and use that instead. Works for me with gcc 7.2.

```
    inline Port myhtons( Port v ) 
    {
            return htons(v);
    }

    class Params final {
    public:
            Ip getIp() const { return ip_; }
            Port getPort() const { return port_; }

    private:
            Ip ip_ {INADDR_ANY};
            Port port_ { myhtons(5) };
    };
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. Its embarrassing that MS's compiler works better than GNU one.